# Navigate from a Flex Application on Ipad to another App

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe, builder

totally a beginner in Flex. I need to know how to place a button on the project which will lunch another local ipad app and closes the current running flex app.

Simply an AIR APP --> Ipad App mapping.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, this is not possible. You can't even do a File#openWithDefaultApplication on the iPad. The sandbox is still too far separated from the actual device, unfortunately.